# Terrraform only deploying part of the infrastructure that is written

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am having what I assume is a simple issue with a Terraform deployment. Both the resource group and vnet are properly being deployed, but the subnet and NSG is not. The error I am seeing on the subnet is:

> Error parsing instance address: azurerm_subnet This command requires
> that the address references one specific instance. To view the
> available instances, use "terraform state list". Please modify the
> address to reference a specific instance.

It seems to be pointing to the correct RG and i have also tried wrapping it in
"${azurerm_resource_group.practiceRG.name}"

Code being used:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      skip_provider_registration = true
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "practiceRG" {
  name     = "testRG"
  location = "East US"
  
  tags = {
    environment = "dev"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "practiceVNET" {
  name                = "testVNET"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.practiceRG.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.practiceRG.location
  address_space       = ["192.168.0.0/16"]

  tags = {
    environment = "dev"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "practiceSubnet" {
  name                 = "testSubnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.practiceRG.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.practiceVNET.name
  address_prefixes     = ["192.168.1.0/24"] 
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "practiceNSG" {
  name                = "testNSG"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.practiceRG.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.practiceRG.location

  tags = {
    environment = "dev"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "practiceRULE" {
  name                        = "allowSSH"
  priority                    = 100
  direction                   = "Inbound"
  access                      = "Allow"
  protocol                    = "TCP"
  source_port_range           = "20.158.2.245"
  destination_port_range      = "*"
  source_address_prefix       = "*"
  destination_address_prefix  = "*"
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.practiceRG.name
  network_security_group_name = azurerm_network_security_group.practiceNSG.name
}
```

Comment: What is the full error message and which line exactly it occurs at?

Comment: terraform state show azurerm_subnet.practiceSubnet                                                       Error parsing instance address: azurerm_subnet

This command requires that the address references one specific instance.
To view the available instances, use "terraform state list". Please modify
the address to reference a specific instance.                                             terraform state show azurerm_network_security_group has same error

Comment: Errors occur at azurerm_subnet, azurerm_network_security_group and azurerm_network_security_rule

Comment: try replacing source_port_range you provided in your azurerm_network_security_rule resource with valid pot range

A single port number (e.g., 22).
A range of ports separated by a hyphen (e.g., 22-443). 
and source_Address_prefix as ""20.158.2.245""
@TrashThrash

Comment: I'm going to be honest with you here. I'm an idiot. Apparently the entire time i never ctrl + s and it was reading from the previous save point. Thank you for responding and trying to help.

Comment: Are you using PowerShell on Windows? This symptom seems like something that often happens with PowerShell when running external commands like Terraform, where it first tries to parse the address as PowerShell syntax and then re-encodes the command line to pass to Terraform, but does so incorrectly so that the single argument gets split into two parts.

Comment: If you _are_ using PowerShell then I suggest trying the same command in `cmd.exe` (Windows Command Prompt) to see if it behaves better there.

Answer (score 0):

> There is nothing like Terraform only deploying part of the infrastructure that is written unless you provide a valid reference point to the resource.

If you want to show a specific instance in the state file, you can use <kbd>terraform show</kbd> which helps to check which references are pointed to each resource.

I worked around the configuration shared and by referring the correct point info to the resource will help you achieve the configuration without any error.

**My Terraform configuration:**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "practiceRG" {
  name     = "testvkRG"
  location = "East US"
  
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "practiceVNET" {
  name                = "testvkVNET"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.practiceRG.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.practiceRG.location
  address_space       = ["192.168.0.0/16"]

  
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "practiceSubnet" {
  name                 = "testvkSubnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.practiceRG.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.practiceVNET.name
  address_prefixes     = ["192.168.1.0/24"] 
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "practiceNSG" {
  name                = "testvkNSG"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.practiceRG.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.practiceRG.location

}

resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "practiceRULE" {
  name                        = "allowSSH"
  priority                    = 100
  direction                   = "Inbound"
  access                      = "Allow"
  protocol                    = "Tcp"
  source_port_range           = "22"
  destination_port_range      = "*"
  source_address_prefix       = "20.158.2.0/24"
  destination_address_prefix  = "*"
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.practiceRG.name
  network_security_group_name = azurerm_network_security_group.practiceNSG.name
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Now to check the list of resources for the reference points

run the command **`terraform show`** to list the resources that exist in the infrastructure.

[image]

From this, you can confirm how the configuration in the editor tool is different from what existed in the state so if we fail to make the reference point right then we will get the mentioned error in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Its was an issue of of the file not saving properly when using powershell to run terraform commands. The fix was ensuring that the file properly saved before running terraform plan